# Sending Mail - Yii 2.0

Tags: php, email, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to send mail, but getting error like.

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>
> Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::mail

After changing `Yii::$app->mail->compose()` to `Yii::$app->mailer->compose()`
I got this error

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
>
> Invalid path alias:@backend/mail

I'm not getting where i'm doing mistake.

I'm using yii-app-basic.

**config/console.php**

```
...
    'components' => [
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        ],
    ],
...
```

**config/web.php**

```
...
    'components' => [
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@backend/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => true,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'port' => '8080',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
    ],
...
```

**SiteController.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\swiftmailer\Mailer;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionRegister()
    {
        Yii::$app->mail->compose()
                ->setFrom('enamRaj@gmail.com')
                ->setTo('Raj@infotech.com')
                ->setSubject('This is a test mail')
                ->send();
    }
}
```

Error Screenshot
[image]

I'm new to Yii. I don't have much idea. If this is a silly question,please forgive me.

Taking help from [Mailing- Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html). But, not getting much idea.
Please help me to send email

Comment: @InsaneSkull. I edited my question. Now, register.php page content is available.

Comment: From what I remember, ```backend``` in yii refers to a different config than the web config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mailer` component.

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
```

---

In your config you write `components` that will be avalible on `Yii::$app` application.

## Example:

In config:

```
'components' => [
    'myComponent' => ['class' => '\common\MyClass']
]
```

In controller:

```
Yii::$app->myComponent->foo();
```

Comment: Got Error Like
Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
Invalid path alias: @backend/mail

Comment: You should write correct path to mail views in param `'viewPath' => '@backend/mail',`

Comment: where to edit Mr @Onedev. Both config.php and web.php have param.
And, what path to give

Comment: Yeah. Got it. just changed 'viewPath' => '@backend/mail', to 'viewPath' => '@app/mail',

Answer (score 0):

You are using the basic template. Path '@backend/mail' is only for advanced template. The correct path is @app/mail (or whatever path where you are storing your email templates).

Answer (score -1):

well it's an old question but if you still using yii if you want to send a mail with no effort use dektrium it's an abandoned project but it provides many features user management email login etc